# Clear localstorage for a specific key

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have stored some information in localstorage and the data storing like :

```
localStorage : 
MessageCount : "[{"id":"user_abc-com","MsgCount":8},{"id":"user2_abc-com","MsgCount":16}]"
```

[image]

Now here I want to make MsgCount = 0 from 8 for a specific id : user_abc-com

So how to do that ?

Comment: parse it, edit it, stringify it, store it again.

Comment: you should extract this object, change value and stringify it back to localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s is your localStorage, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knk7eggv/)

```
var s = "[{\"id\":\"user_abc-com\",\"MsgCount\":8},{\"id\":\"user2_abc-com\",\"MsgCount\":16}]";
var s_obj = JSON.parse(s); // parsing it from string to object

s_obj.forEach(function(v, k) { // iterate through array
    if(v.id == 'user_abc-com') s_obj[k].MsgCount = 0 // change value
});

s = JSON.stringify(s_obj); // switching to string again (ready to save in localStorage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply update your element with new value:

```js
var messages = [
  {"id": "user_abc-com", "MsgCount": 8},
  {"id": "user2_abc-com", "MsgCount": 16}
];

localStorage.setItem('MessageCount', JSON.stringify(messages));

// ----------- //

var messages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MessageCount'));
messages[0]['MsgCount'] = 0;
localStorage.setItem('MessageCount', JSON.stringify(messages));

// ----------- //

console.log(localStorage.getItem('MessageCount'));
```

Comment: Thanks my friend but the solution provided by  Sojtin  is much better as its fetching dynamic array key where you are using messages[0]. Thanks again for your help